# Вылетает Android Studio на этапе открытия проекта

Tags: java, android-studio

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION (0xc000001d) at pc=0x000000000847188b, pid=1636, tid=7968
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.8+10) (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.8+10-b944.6842174, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# J 23486 c1 kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.SmallSortedMap.get(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (43 bytes) @ 0x000000000847188b [0x00000000084717e0+0x00000000000000ab]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

После установки периодически выбрасывает из студии. Бывает загрузит проект, бывает сразу после открытия выбросит. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спустя время проблема была решена и, может быть, для кого-то это так-же будет решением. Для корректной работы Android Studio необходимо минимум 8гб оперативной памяти. В моем случае это помогло

Answer (score 0):

1 - Убедитесь , что ваша версия openjdk не ниже 8

2 -Вспомните , не было ли проблем на этапе установки самого jdk

3 - Желательно чтобы не было русских символов на пути к проекту

4 - Попробуйте запустить от имени администратора

Возможно это поможет

Comment: Все пункты пройдены, результат не изменился. Переустанавливается студия, после чего дам обратку. Спасибо за попытку помочь:)

Answer (score -1):

Проблемы с OpenJDK.

Поэтому поводу почитайте на github [тут](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/30001) и [тут](https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues/58)

Comment: Обсуждения не подходят под тему. Проблема заключается в спонтанном закрытии студии. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в лоб изменить путь к JDK?